# Boost Spirit X3 multiple copy constructors specified

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have a annoying warning when inheriting from x3::variant using Boost 1.69.0 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and 2019:

```
warning C4521: 'boost::spirit::x3::variant<int>': multiple copy constructors specified
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::x3::variant<int>' being compiled
```

This is triggered by this code:

```
#include "boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp"
struct si : boost::spirit::x3::variant<int> {};
int main() { si s; }
```

What can I do to get rid of this warning?

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f4f496a0a18eee4

Comment: I can get rid of this by removing the copy constructor `variant(variant& rhs)` in variant.hpp. But I rather would not like to edit the boost code.

Comment: Are you asking how to suppress warnings in general with that compiler?  If you aren’t editing the code, that’s about the only option left…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do to get rid of this warning?

- Download Boost 1.70
- Disable the warning globally
- Suppress the warning by temporary disabling it before Boost includes
- Tell you compiler to not treat Boost headers as your own, but as system headers (in GCC by using `-isystem-includes` instead of `-I`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick to 1.69.0 and want to fix it in the code you can remove lines 152-153 in spirit\home\x3\support\ast\variant.hpp

```
    variant(variant& rhs) BOOST_NOEXCEPT_IF((std::is_nothrow_constructible<variant_type, variant_type&>::value))
        : var(rhs.var) {}
```

(Because in lines 149-150 another copy constructor with a const argument it is defined).